# HTML BUTTON WITH TEXT AND IMAGE

Tags: html, button

I am in a beginner programming class. We are only on chapter 4, so please keep that in mind. This class is using HTML with some `javascript`, we haven't really gotten too deep into `javascript` yet. My project for this week is to create two buttons, and when each one of these buttons are clicked a photo and a paragraph comes up. I have the button with the paragraph coming up but I can't figure out how to add the image. Everything I have found on the internet is super `javascript`, stuff I haven't learned. Here is my code, I just picked a random topic, haha

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--Web page that displays quotes at the click of a button click. -->
<!--============================================================= -->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <p>
      <h2> <span style="color:red">Favorite Animals</span> </h2>
    </p>


    <input type="button" value="Slow Loris" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
    'This animal might look like a harmless, big-eyed baby ewok, but ' +
    'the slow loris is one of the only venomous mammals in the world. ' +
    'Its subtle nature makes it popular in the illegal pet trade, but this ' +
    'furry creature also carries a toxin that is released from the brachial ' +
    'gland on the sides of its elbows. If threatened, the loris can take ' +
    'the toxin into its mouth and mix it with saliva. The animal may also ' +
    'lick or rub its hair with this mixture to deter predators from attack. ' +
    'The toxin can cause death by anaphylactic shock in some people.';">

    <input type="button" value="Sloth" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
    'Sloths—the sluggish tree-dwellers of Central and South America—spend ' +
    'their lives in the tropical rain forests. They move through the canopy ' +
    'at a rate of about 40 yards per day, munching on leaves, twigs and buds. ' +
    'Sloths have an exceptionally low metabolic rate and spend 15 to 20 hours ' +
    'per day sleeping. And surprisingly enough, the long-armed animals are ' + 
    'excellent swimmers. They occasionally drop from their treetop perches ' +
    'into water for a paddle.';">
  </div>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On click of the button, you want an image and the paragraph to be inserted in the outputDiv. Is that right?

Comment: Chelsea you are looking at this the wrong way. Why dont you make those divs with images and text iniside them, and clicking the buttons will just show them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'style' property of `<img>` to achieve what you are looking for. Within the style property you could set `display:none`, to hide the `<img>`. To make it visible again, just change display back to `display:inline` when a button gets clicked. Try the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--Web page that displays quotes at the click of a button click. -->
<!--============================================================= -->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Project2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
<p>
<h2> <span style="color:red">Favorite Animals</span> </h2>
<img id='slow' src='slowLoris.jpg' alt='Slow Loris' style='width:200px;height:150px;display:none;'>
<img id='sloth' src='sloth.jpg' alt='Sloth' style='width:200px;height:150px;display:none;'>
</p>


<input type="button" value="Slow Loris"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="
document.getElementById('sloth').style='width:200px;height:150px;display:none;'
document.getElementById('slow').style='width:200px;height:150px;display:inline;'
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
'This animal might look like a harmless, big-eyed baby ewok, but ' +
'the slow loris is one of the only venomous mammals in the world. ' +
'Its subtle nature makes it popular in the illegal pet trade, but this ' +
'furry creature also carries a toxin that is released from the brachial ' +
'gland on the sides of its elbows. If threatened, the loris can take ' +
'the toxin into its mouth and mix it with saliva. The animal may also ' +
'lick or rub its hair with this mixture to deter predators from attack. ' +
'The toxin can cause death by anaphylactic shock in some people.';">

<input type="button" value="Sloth"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="
document.getElementById('slow').style='width:200px;height:150px;display:none';
document.getElementById('sloth').style='width:200px;height:150px;display:inline;'
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
'Sloths—the sluggish tree-dwellers of Central and South America—spend ' +
'their lives in the tropical rain forests. They move through the canopy ' +
'at a rate of about 40 yards per day, munching on leaves, twigs and buds. ' +
'Sloths have an exceptionally low metabolic rate and spend 15 to 20 hours ' +
'per day sleeping. And surprisingly enough, the long-armed animals are ' + 
'excellent swimmers. They occasionally drop from their treetop perches ' +
'into water for a paddle.'"> 
</div>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** 
 
If you don't mind changing your code a bit, a cleaner solution would be:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--Web page that displays quotes at the click of a button click. -->
<!--============================================================= -->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Project2</title>
</head>
<body style='text-align:center'>

<h2> <span style="color:red">Favorite Animals</span> </h2>

<div id='slow' style='text-align:center;display:none'>     
    <img src='slowLoris.jpg' alt='Slow Loris'>
    <p>This animal might look like a harmless, big-eyed baby ewok, but 
        the slow loris is one of the only venomous mammals in the world.
        Its subtle nature makes it popular in the illegal pet trade, but this 
        furry creature also carries a toxin that is released from the brachial 
        gland on the sides of its elbows. If threatened, the loris can take 
        the toxin into its mouth and mix it with saliva. The animal may also 
        lick or rub its hair with this mixture to deter predators from attack. 
        The toxin can cause death by anaphylactic shock in some people.</p>
</div>

<div id='sloth' style='text-align:center;display:none'>    
    <img src='sloth.jpg' alt='Sloth'>
    <p> Sloths—the sluggish tree-dwellers of Central and South America—spend
        their lives in the tropical rain forests. They move through the canopy
        at a rate of about 40 yards per day, munching on leaves, twigs and buds. 
        sloths have an exceptionally low metabolic rate and spend 15 to 20 hours
        per day sleeping. And surprisingly enough, the long-armed animals are 
        excellent swimmers. They occasionally drop from their treetop perches 
        into water for a paddle.</p>
</div>


<input type="button" value="Slow Loris"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="
document.getElementById('slow').style='text-align:center;display:inline';
document.getElementById('sloth').style='text-align:center;display:none'">

<input type="button" value="Sloth"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="
document.getElementById('sloth').style='text-align:center;display:inline';
document.getElementById('slow').style='text-align:center;display:none'">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple just put the image inside, see jsfiddle

```
<input type="button" value="Slow Loris"
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
'<img src=https://www.thepharmaletter.com/media/image/actavis-logo-small.jpg>' +
'This animal might look like a harmless, big-eyed baby ewok, but ' +
'the slow loris is one of the only venomous mammals in the world. ' +
'Its subtle nature makes it popular in the illegal pet trade, but this ' +
'furry creature also carries a toxin that is released from the brachial ' +
'gland on the sides of its elbows. If threatened, the loris can take ' +
'the toxin into its mouth and mix it with saliva. The animal may also ' +
'lick or rub its hair with this mixture to deter predators from attack. ' +
'The toxin can cause death by anaphylactic shock in some people.';">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxcz3f8g/

Answer (score 0):

As the property name suggests, `innerHTML` can be a full blown HTML content and not just text. You can put any valid HTML in that. And as per good practices, you should write those operations in a separate js file and import it.

```js
function addContent(event) {
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
    '<img width="80" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n7gcats5uCQ/maxresdefault.jpg"/><br/><p>Sloths—the sluggish tree-dwellers of Central and South America—spend ' +
    'their lives in the tropical rain forests. They move through the canopy ' +
    'at a rate of about 40 yards per day, munching on leaves, twigs and buds. ' +
    'Sloths have an exceptionally low metabolic rate and spend 15 to 20 hours ' +
    'per day sleeping. And surprisingly enough, the long-armed animals are ' +
    'excellent swimmers. They occasionally drop from their treetop perches ' +
    'into water for a paddle.</p>'
}
```

```html
<button onClick="addContent()">Sloth</button>
<div id="outputDiv" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use image tag `<img>` to insert images, e.g.

```
<img src="https://www.internationalanimalrescue.org/sites/default/files/sumatran_slow_loris.jpg">
```

Here the value of `src` points to the source of the image. You can use one from your computer too (just specify its relative path from your html file).

A few other points. You can use `<button>` to create button. `<input>` is to create user input fields. And it's better to separate your HTMl from your Javascript code and then just toggle its display property with your code (you can also move these code to a separate place from your button creation, if you've already learned it).

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
<p>
<h2> <span style="color:red">Favorite Animals</span> </h2>
</p>


<button type="button" 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv1').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('outputDiv2').style.display = 'none'">Slow Loris</button>

<button type="button" 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"
onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv2').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('outputDiv1').style.display = 'none'"> Sloth</button>

</div>

<div id="outputDiv1" style="display:none">slow loris<img src="https://www.internationalanimalrescue.org/sites/default/files/sumatran_slow_loris.jpg" alt="loris" height="100" width="140"></div>
<div id="outputDiv2" style="display:none">sloth<img src="http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Mammals/Q-Z/sloth-beach-upside-down.adapt.945.1.jpg" alt="sloth" height="100" width="140"></div>
```